# How can I check if any of the values in a column with comma seaparated values are in another table in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I have a table like so:

| IDs | data |
| --- | --- |
| one, two | a |
| three, four one | b |
| five, six | c |
| seven | d |
| eight, nine, three | e |

I have another table like so:

| ID |
| --- |
| one |
| four |
| six |
| nine |

I need to add a column to the first table that will tell me if any of the values in the `IDs` column are in the `ID` column of the other table.

If it matters, both ables have 200,000+ rows.

I am on Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2021. It does not have many of the newer functions like TEXTSPLIT. :(

Comment: Would `=MMULT(IFERROR(FIND(", ,",SUBSTITUTE(", "&A2:A6&", ",TRANSPOSE(F2:F5),)),),SEQUENCE(ROWS(F2:F5))^0)>0` work for you where `A2:A6` are your IDs and `F2:F5` the ID-column.

Answer (score 2):

### Match Delimited

[image]

- In the first (data) row of column `Found` use:

  ```
  =COUNT(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT([@IDs],", "),Table2[ID]))>0
  ```

Or:

[image]

```
=LET(data,[@IDs],sdlm,", ",ddlm,"-",ignore_blanks,1,if_not_found,NA(),
    d,TEXTSPLIT([@IDs],sdlm),
    m,XMATCH(d,Table2[ID]),
IF(COUNT(m)=0,if_not_found,
    TEXTJOIN(ddlm,ignore_blanks,FILTER(d,ISNUMBER(m)))))
```

Comment: Doh. I am on Excel Professional Plus 2021 and it doesn't have those functions. :(

Answer (score 0):

My approach is here..

```
=LOOKUP(2^55,SEARCH($F$5:$F$8,SUBSTITUTE(B5,",","")),$F$5:$F$8)
```

`you can use IFERROR function to eliminate #NA`

[image: Result]